# fetching record according current date

Tags: php, mysql

can any one explain how i would display my table record according date, like any user of my website can see their activity of current date only...

```
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
    $data["create_date"]=date("M d,y" , $data[create_date]);
```

i am using this but it displaying previous date result also

here is my code, i am fetching result from different tables

```
$SQL="select * from  $tab  where 1 $con ORDER BY id desc $_REQUEST[sort_mode] $con_limit";
     while($data=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
        {
        $data["create_date"]=date("M d,y" , $data[create_date]);

    gri("users","WHERE id='$data[op_id]' ","",$op_name);
    gri("patient", " where id ='$data[patient_id]' order by id desc","",$patient);
        $data[first_name]=$patient[first_name];
        $data[last_name]=$patient[last_name];
        $data[age]=$patient[age];$data[sex]=$patient[sex];
        $data[mob]=$patient[mob];
        $data[op_name]=$op_name[name];
        $t->set_var($data);
        $t->set_var(array("chk_status_$data[id]_$data[status]"=>"selected",));
        $t->parse("ABlockList","AccessBlockList",true);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the main sql query out of which you are running while loop?

Comment: forget `'`  for `$data["create_date"]=date("M d,y" , $data['create_date']);`

Comment: I think we also need to see your schema for the tables you're looking at, but it could be as simple as adding `WHERE DATE(datetimecolumn) = CURDATE()` to your query.

Comment: sir this is query, $SQL="select * from  $tab  where 1 $con ORDER BY id desc $_REQUEST[sort_mode] $con_limit";

Comment: @DineshKumar Please, add it to your question and format it.

Comment: Okay, @DineshKumar, What's in $tab, $con, $_REQUEST[sort_mode], and $con_limit?  It's a little hard to see what your query is when you've abstracted it so far.  We need a Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example to be able to help.  See http://SSCCE.org

Comment: if i do this echo $data["create_date"], i got these date "Mar 30,13 Mar 30,13 Mar 30,13 Mar 30,13Mar 30,13 Mar 30,13 Mar 31,13Mar 30,13 Mar 30,13 Mar 29,13", is there any process to neglet previous date result these date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `MySQL` for this.

**Example**

```
select * from table_name where create_date >= NOW();
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name  WHERE DATE(create_date) = CURDATE();
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE(create_date) = DATE(NOW())
```

> `DATE()` returns the date without time and `NOW()` returns the current `date & time` (note we’ve used the DATE() function in this query to remove the time)

Comment: Mmm... If create_date is a datetime column, that'll only show things that were created after the select began.  Not really the same as "Today's activity".

Comment: @DineshKumar what result its giving...??? does your table field is `date` or `datetime`.??

Comment: create_date is my field name

Comment: its date dipesh, any way to sort out this??

Comment: @DineshKumar share your `database` table structure with some data...if you can.

Comment: @dipesh my all query are fine and if i echo this $data['create_date'] then i got an array of date like Mar 30,13 Mar 30,13 Mar 30,13 Mar 30,13 Mar 30,13 Mar 30,13 Mar 29,13 Mar 29,13 Mar 29,13 Mar 29,13, ....i am just hoping a condition where i can display my result according Mar 30, 13(current date)...:)

Comment: @DineshKumar above answered query do that for you...you do not need to check its in php condition for today date because above all queries do it in mysql....